# Post from Android to mysql php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I started a project in which I want to manage few databases with php script from my app.
Reading the database was very easy, I'm having problem with adding anything to the database while trying to use HttpUrlConnection and Uri.Builder.
I must say that I don't know php but if I enter the user name and pssword manualy into the php sprict its working, so the problem is in the uri builder or in the _POST in php.

does anyone have other sulotion/can find the issue in my code.

### Android:

```
myUrl = new URL("http://www.traveling.esy.es/postToPhp.php");

conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
     .appendQueryParameter("USER_NAME", "" + userEditText.getText().toString())
     .appendQueryParameter("PASSWORD", "" + passEditText.getText().toString());

String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

PHP:

---

```
<?php
$server_name = "correct_database_info";
$user_name = "correct_database_info";
$password = "correct_database_info";
$database_name = "correct_database_info";
$users_table = "correct_database_info";


***$user_name_post = $_POST["USER_NAME"];
$password_post = $_POST["PASSWORD"];***


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password, $database_name);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //echo "Successfully connected to Database" . "<br>";


    ***$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (`USER_NO`, `USER_ID`, `USER_NAME`, `USER_IMAGE`, `USER_LOCATION`) VALUES (NULL, '34', '$user_name_post' , '$password_post', 'home')";***


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer myself.
I Used URLEncoder Class to post, at first I t didn't worked, seems Like I had to add the input stream for it to work (I have no idea why).

Heres the updated android code:

```
myUrl = new URL("http://www.traveling.esy.es/postToPhp.php");
conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);


String name = userEditText.getText().toString();
String pass = passEditText.getText().toString();

String data = URLEncoder.encode("USER_NAME", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("PASSWORD", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();


BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
bufferedWriter.write(data);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();

InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
String response = "";
String line = "";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
     response+= line;
}
bufferedReader.close();
inputStream.close();
conn.disconnect();
os.close();

Log.d("POST_DEBUG", "INPUT:" + response);
Log.d("POST_DEBUG", ""+data);
```